# Find the zeros of $h(z)=\frac{1}{3}e^z-z$ inside $\mid z \mid \leq 1$ - Rouche's Theorem Application

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, analytic-functions

The question is to find the zeros of $h(z)=\frac{1}{3}e^z-z$ inside $\mid z \mid \leq 1$

Preparing for an application of Rouche's theorem with $f(z)=\frac{1}{3}e^z$ and $g(z)=-z$ it is easy to see that $\mid g(z) \mid=\mid e^{i \theta} \mid=1$

However, I'm not sure how to investigate the behavior of $\mid f(z) \mid $ on the boundary of the unit disc, which is a usual problem I run into in applications of Rouche's Theorem.

$\mid f(z) \mid = \frac{1}{3}\mid e^z \mid=?$

Plugging in $z=e^{i\theta}$ is the only tool I have, and it doesn't seem to be useful here.

Comment: What does it mean *to find the zeroes of $h(z)$*? As a consequence of Picard's little theorem, such function has an infinite number of zeroes in the complex plane. Did you mean *how many zeroes of $h(z)$ lie inside the unit disk centered at the origin*? That is quite a different question.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm sorry yes I meant in the unit disc, let me add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z$ fulfills $|z|\leq 1$ then $\left|\frac{1}{3}e^z\right| = \frac{1}{3} e^{\text{Re}(z)} \leq \frac{e}{3} < 1$, in particular on the boundary of the unit disk the function $\frac{1}{3}e^{z}$ is always smaller that $z$ (or $-z$) in absolute value. It follows that the number of zeroes of $h(z)$ inside the unit disk is the same as the number of zeroes of $-z$ inside the unit disk, i.e. $\color{red}{\large 1}$. Such zero is real and belong to the interval $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, so I am assuming that when investigating the modulus on the boundary, I can substitute the real part of $z$ in the expression and observe how that behaves.

Comment: @Craig: I am not assuming anything, the modulus of $e^{z}$ is $e^{\text{Re}(z)}$ and if $|z|\leq 1$ then $\text{Re}(z)\leq 1$. At most, I am exploiting the fact that $z\to e^z$ is increasing on the real line.