# Using Rouche’s Theorem find the number of points $e^{z}+3z=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Use Rouche’s Theorem to determine for how many points $z\in D(0,1)$ we have $e^{z}+3z=0$.

Comment: Hi, I didn't downvote you but $1)$ it's important that you *tell us what you've tried*, and $2)$ it would help if you used $\LaTeX$ formatting.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246612/find-the-zeros-of-hz-frac13ez-z-inside-mid-z-mid-leq-1-rouches?s=9|0.0000 and related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249855/number-of-solutions-to-ez-3z-1-0-in-the-unit-disk?s=8|0.0000

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(z)=3z$ and $g(z)=e^z$. Then $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ for all $z$ in $C: |z|=1$. 
$$|g(z)|=|e^z|=e^{Re\; z}\leq e<3=|f(z)|$$
So Rouche's theorem gives that $f$ and $f+g$ must have same number of zeros inside of $C$. Clearly, $f$ has only one zero inside of $C$.